How to change the pageLoadStrategy for a specific test/test suite?
I have a page for which I write autotests to fill out the form. The form elements are loaded immediately, but background requests do not allow the browser to return the page loading event. Therefore, with the default Configuration.pageLoadStrategy = "normal" I'm falling on timeout.
I don't want to increase the timeouts, so I looked in the direction of changing the pageLoadStrategy = "eager". Is it possible to set this setting only for a specific test or a set of tests?
Selenide version: 7.6.0
Chrome version: 128.0
public class QaFormTest extends BaseTestRemote {
    RegistrationPage registrationPage = new RegistrationPage();
    Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("en"));

    private final LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(faker.date().birthday().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    private final Map<String, List<String>> stateAndCity = Map.of(
            "NCR", List.of("Delhi", "Gurgaon", "Noida"),
            "Uttar Pradesh", List.of("Agra", "Lucknow", "Merrut"),
            "Haryana", List.of("Karnal", "Panipat"),
            "Rajasthan", List.of("Jaipur", "Jaiselmer")
    );
    private final Map.Entry<String, String> randomStateAndCity = RandomElement.fromMap(stateAndCity);
    private final List<String> genders = List.of("Male", "Female", "Other");
    private final String
            firstName = faker.name().firstName(),
            lastName = faker.name().lastName(),
            email = faker.internet().emailAddress(),
            phoneNumber = faker.phoneNumber().subscriberNumber(10),
            gender = RandomElement.fromList(genders),
            birthDay = String.format("%02d", birthDate.getDayOfMonth()),
            birthMonth = birthDate.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH),
            birthYear = String.valueOf(birthDate.getYear()),
            picturePath = "eva.jpg",
            address = faker.address().fullAddress(),
            state = randomStateAndCity.getKey(),
            city = randomStateAndCity.getValue();
    private final List<String>
            hobbies = List.of("Sports", "Reading", "Music"),
            subjects = List.of("Maths", "Physics", "Computer Science");

    @Test
    @Tag("UI")
    @DisplayName("Check registration form: https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
    void RegistrationPageShouldSubmitFilledForm() {
        step("Open form", () -> {
            registrationPage.openPage();
        });

        step("Fill form", () -> {
            registrationPage
                    .setFirstName(firstName)
                    .setLastName(lastName)
                    .setEmail(email)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .setGender(gender)
                    .setBirthDate(birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear)
                    .setSubjects(subjects)
                    .setHobbies(hobbies)
                    .uploadPictureFromClassPath(picturePath)
                    .setAddressInfo(address)
                    .setState(state)
                    .setCity(city);
        });

        step("Submit form", () -> {
            registrationPage.submit();
        });

        step("Verify results", () -> {
            registrationPage.verifyResultsModalAppears()
                    .verifyResult("Student Name", String.format("%s %s", firstName, lastName))
                    .verifyResult("Student Email", email)
                    .verifyResult("Gender", gender)
                    .verifyResult("Mobile", phoneNumber)
                    .verifyResult("Date of Birth", String.format("%s %s,%s", birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear))
                    .verifyResult("Subjects", String.join(", ", subjects))
                    .verifyResult("Hobbies", String.join(", ", hobbies))
                    .verifyResult("Address", address)
                    .verifyResult("State and City", String.format("%s %s", state, city))
                    .verifyResult("Picture", picturePath);
        });
    }
}

public class BaseTestRemote {

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        Configuration.baseUrl = BASE_URL;
        Configuration.browser = BROWSER_NAME;
        Configuration.browserVersion = BROWSER_VERSION;
        Configuration.browserSize = BROWSER_EXC;
        Configuration.remote = SELENOID_URL + "/wd/hub";
        
        Configuration.pageLoadStrategy = "eager";

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("selenoid:options", Map.<String, Object>of(
                "enableVNC", true,
                "enableVideo", true
        ));

        Configuration.browserCapabilities = capabilities;
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void addListener() {
        SelenideLogger.addListener("AllureSelenide", new AllureSelenide());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void addAttachments() {
        Attach.screenshotAs("Last screenshot");
        Attach.pageSource();
        Attach.browserConsoleLogs();
        Attach.addVideo();
    }
}

